Rigify shoulder bone not parented to rig's shoulder widget
the rigify shoulder bone and widget share the same pivot point location yet the widget does not move the bone. what is the purpose of this?
can somebody help me remove the 4L lock on the bone so i can parent it to the shoulder widget?
also noticed that the arm bone is not parented to the shoulder. this would make the rig so much cleaner. am i missing something?


Which Blender/Rigify version do you use? Have you changed the meta rig? If I generate the rig from the meta rig in Blender 4.1 then the arm bones are connected to the shoulder bones.

im in blender 4 but the rig was generated in 2.9 or so i believe.
so i am correct in thinking that it should be linked?
